# Differential equation solution (Confusion)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to prepare for my final exam and I was trying to solve a problem.

The problem is as follows: $y^k = 0$ (I need to find all solutions)

Initially, I though the answer would be as follows:

$(y^{k-1}) = c$

$(y^{k-2}) = cx$

$(y^{k-3}) = cx^2$ ( I thought the c should be able to take care of the 1/2)

$(y^{k-4}) = cx^3$

$(y) = cx^{k-2}$

But then I started thinking that that $(y^{k-2}) = cx$ should also have a constant so should the answer look more like $(y) = cx^{k-2} + c_1x^{k-3} + ... + c$

Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: Your second thought is correct, but you need to use different $c$'s for each constant.

Comment: @kccu would that be $c_{k-1}$ or can I get away with $c_{n}$?

Comment: $n$ does not have any meaning in this context, so I would relate the subscripts to $k$. There are different choices in how you could do this, e.g., starting at $0$: $c_0x^{k-2} + c_1 x^{k-3} + \cdots + c_{k-2}$, or matching them to the exponents: $c_{k-2}x^{k-2} + c_{k-1}x^{k-1} + \cdots + c_0$, or something else.